# Git - Remote Prune All Branches That Match A Regular Expression From Dry Run

Tags: git

The documentation for `git remote prune` seems sparse.

Lets say we have done a prune dry run and have the following results:

```
 * [would prune] origin/release/app
 * [would prune] origin/release/appDynamics
 * [would prune] origin/release/xu-88.3
```

It it possible to follow through with a `git prune` that only prunes branches that start with `xu`?

Comment: `git prune` is about *objects*, not branch names. Did you mean `git remote prune`?

Comment: @torek yes, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no: the `[would prune] origin/release/app` tells you that over on `origin`, `release/app` no longer exists so `git fetch -p` or `git remote prune` "wants" to remove your remote-tracking name that no longer corresponds to their (nonexistent) `release/app`.  There's no directive to `git fetch -p` (or `git remote prune`) that gives it a glob pattern of branch names to match up.

You can, however, save the `[would prune]` output into a *file*, read the file, do your own pattern matching, and run `git update-ref -d` on each `refs/remotes/origin/release/xu*` name.  That's just a small matter of programming.

(The more interesting question to me is why you want to hang on to `refs/remotes/origin/release/app` when there's no `refs/heads/release/app` in the Git repository at `origin`.  But that's not what you asked. :-) )